# Userscript, to replace icons on Stack Exchange pages, spams background images where the icons should be

Tags: css, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a user script to fix the problem that highlighted editor icons have the wrong colour in the new Stack Exchange design (at least on sites which use a different primary colour, such as tex.stackexchange, described in more detail in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317581/237989)

[image: Screenshot of SE editor]

I tried the following code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange TEX, adjust css
// @match       *://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `

    .wmd-button{
        background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/9T3.svg") !important;
    }

` );
```

but this results in

[image: Stuttering "B"s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

1. That script is styling the wrong node. The page source <sup>([Link to typical example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/6668))</sup> is like:

   ```
   <li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-code-button" title="Code Sample <pre><code> Ctrl+K">
       <span style="background-position: -80px 0px;"></span>
   </li>
   ```

   So, nominally, you would style `.wmd-button > span`, **But...**
2. You want to play nice with other brilliant scripts/extensions ([Example](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-superscript-and-subscript-markup-shortcuts)), so use `.wmd-button[id] > span` to reduce side-effects.
3. Since svgshare.com has proven large downtimes, you may want to convert that image to PNG format and host it on i.stack.imgur.com.

So your script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange TEX, fix edit-icon hover colors
// @description Adulterates that beautiful, beautiful orange.
// @match       *://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `

    .wmd-button[id] > span {
        background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/9T3.svg") !important;
    }

` );
```

Comment: And again your are my hero! Thanks a lot! About 2. You are totally right, I would not want to break such a brilliant script by such a great author :) 3. In reality I just have my files locally for my own use, but in order to make a short transportable example, I replaced them by the svgshare link, but thanks for your concerns!

Comment: Actually I have to thank you one more time: thanks for mentioning the kbd script - I just installed it and especially the strike through button is a fantastic idea! I tried a million times to remember the syntax, but I'll always confuse myself if it is `strike`, or `del` or whatever.

Comment: @samcarter glad you like it -- and that you haven't asked me to change the hover color ;) .

Comment: Luckily your code is much easier to read than the code from stackexchange, so finding the orange was no problem :)